# Find any string that starts with a specified search word and is followed by another capital word

Tags: regex, ide, webstorm

We have some bad code that has been written where there is a redundant word in object property names and we're trying to find these culprits throughout the entire application using search and replace.

To give you an example, imagine a person object having its properties also contain the word person, i.e.

```
var person = new Person();
person.personName = 'Mark';
person.personAge = 20;
```

In this instance, we know the word `person` but don't know all of the properties that have been set on that object throughout an application.

Using Regex, are we able to find anything matching person*, where the wildcard is always a capital letter, i.e. camelCase? We want to replace `personName` with just `name`.

I thought about searching for `.person` but it's given me lots of unwanted results.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to search inside the js or using the IDE ?

Comment: @kappaismyname you're right the javascript tag wasn't needed. I have removed it. Trying to search in the IDE, namely WebStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regular expression works for me in sublime (not sure which IDE you're using) when I search the project:

`\.person[A-Z]`

explained:

`\.` is to match a period (you have to escape it in a regular expression because otherwise it means match any single character)

`person` is to match just person

`[A-Z]` is to match any capital character

Comment: That's it, nice and easy. Will accept in 8 minutes. Cheers